# Where is the function get_example_data in matplotlib? It seems to be missing but its in examples/tutorials

Tags: python, graph, visualization, matplotlib

Looking at this tutorial here: [link text](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/plot_directive/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/finance_work2.py) it references matplotlib.get_example_data('goog.npy'). I get an error when I run this, and furthermore I can't even find the mpl-data/ folder in my macosx installation of matplot lib when searching using Spotlight. Any idea what this function is now called?

Comment: What version do you have?  I have 'python-matplotlib-0.98.5.2-1.1', and the function you mention is available.  In addition, I can open the following file:  site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/example/goog.npy

Comment: Where is site-packages? Off of where in the root of your disk? I can't find that file at all in osx, and I've installed the same version of matplot lib twice now straight from their sourceforge repository.

Comment: full path on 64-bit Linux:  /usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/example/goog.npy

Comment: And I found this link which has some Mac-specific installation instructions:  http://www.soton.ac.uk/~fangohr/computing/pythonsoft.html

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in `__init__.py` (around line 490), if that's what you're asking.

-- MarkusQ

P.S. The `mpl_data/` directory is there too (both of them are in the top level directory).  Are you sure you've got a good / complete installation?

Comment: My installation came with an Enthough distribution. I am on an iMac and can't find any of this stuff. Where is it installed by default on unix machines?

Comment: Try using 'locate' or 'find' to determine where it is on your machine (since that's what you're really interested in).

Comment: OK I found the __init__.py for matplotlib on my machine, but it does not have get_example_data defined in it nor does it have goog.npy in its mpl-data folder. Maybe the problem is that its using 98.3.0001 which comes with Enthought's distribution, where as the newer version 98.5 has it defined.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar (the same?) problem for Ubuntu 10.04 (Python 2.6.5, MPL 0.99.1.1).

There was no `get_sample_data`, however a `get_example_data` in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/__init__.py` which didn't really work. The directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages` was empty.

As a workaround, I downloaded the file [goog.npy](https://github.com/matplotlib/sample_data/blob/master/goog.npy) directly and replaced the loading of the data with (probably similar)

```
with open("goog.npy") as f:
  r = np.load(f).view(np.recarray)
```